# Get Root DOM element from a child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a loop that reads multiple elements from the document and I render it with `ReactDOM.render`, and a component very low in the component tree, creates a `custom event`, to that event I would like to pass the element that was rendered in the DOM (i.e. Root Element), I have to go passing from the top the element through Props, or React provides some API that can tell me which Root element we are?

Rather, in the child component, I would like to make: `rootElement.dispatchEvent(myCustomEvent)`;

What options do I have to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root node looks to be given a property that starts with `__reactContainer`, so you can search through parent elements until you find an element with such a property.

```js
const Child = () => <div><span onClick={(e) => {
  let element = e.target;
  while (element) {
    element = element.parentElement;
    if (Object.keys(element).some(key => key.includes('reactContainer'))) {
      console.log('Found', element);
      break;
    }
  }
}}>click</span></div>;
const App = () => {
    return <section><Child /></section>
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

That's almost certainly not part of the deliberate outward-facing design, though. A better way would be to use `useContext` to save the root element at the top component via a ref, and to consume it in the descendant component.

```js
const Child = () => {
  const { ref } = React.useContext(Context);
  return (
    <div>
      <span
        onClick={() => { console.log(ref.current.parentElement); }}
      >click</span>
    </div>
  );
};

const Context = React.createContext();
const App = () => {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  return (
    <Context.Provider value={{ref}}>
      <section ref={ref}><Child /></section>
    </Context.Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Impressive. Thank you very much. I have learned two new things. :)